An inequality for continuity of normal derivative of double layer potential
Let $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^2$ smooth Jordan curve,  $t_x$,$n_x$ be the tangent and exterior normal of $x \in \Gamma$ respectively.
$$
U(x,t_x,\delta,n_x,\delta) := \{ y = x + \xi t_x + \eta n_x : \vert \xi \vert, \vert \eta \vert  \leq \delta \}
$$
$$
\Gamma(x,\delta) := U(x,t_x,\delta,n_x,\delta) \cap \Gamma = \{ y = x + \xi t_x + f_x(\xi)  n_x : \vert \xi \vert \leq \delta \}
$$
where $\delta>0$ is sufficiently small constant and independent of $x$, $f_x(\xi) \in C^2[-\delta,\delta]$, $f_x(0) = 0$, $f'_x(0) = 0$.
Can we prove that, for fixed $x \in \Gamma$, with $h>0$ sufficiently small,
\begin{equation}
\vert (t_x \cdot \nabla_z) (t_y \cdot \nabla_y) \frac{(z_1 - y_1)^2}{\vert z -y \vert^2} |_{z = x+h n_x} - (t_x \cdot \nabla_z) (t_y \cdot \nabla_y) \frac{(z_1 - y_1)^2}{\vert z -y \vert^2} |_{z = x-h n_x} \vert \leq C \frac{h}{\xi^2 + h^2}
\end{equation}
holds for all $y \in \Gamma(x,\delta)$?
